# got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop when doing Lock.acquire()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Got a problem with asyncio.

I have a function that splits a dataset, iterates over the parts, and then creates a separate asyncio task for each of them using `asyncio.create_task(do_operation)`, then saves that future into an array `jobs`.

Inside, `do_operation` does select + update in the database, and I don't want to run into any race conditions, and so for that I am using `asyncio.Lock()`.

After the loop, another task is created with `asyncio.create_task(wait_for_all_to_finish_and_then_complete())`, in which we wait for all jobs to finish using `await asyncio.gather(*jobs, return_exceptions=True)`.

The problem is, sometimes, when doing `Lock.acquire()`, I get this exception:

```
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-69' coro=<run_scoring_operation() running at ***> cb=[gather.<locals>._done_callback() at /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py:769]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

Why does it happen and how to solve it?

Comment: Seem `threading` is used. All asyncio Task, Future, Lock, must stay in the same thread they are created. Please provide minimal reproducible example.